# Show that if $a_1b_2 − a_2b_1 = \pm 1$, then the gcd of $(a_1 + a_2, b_1 + b_2) = 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Show that if $a_1b_2 − a_2b_1 = \pm 1$, then the gcd of $(a_1 + a_2, b_1 + b_2) = 1$.
I don't know how to deduce that.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$b_1(a_1+a_2)-a_1(b_1+b_2)=?$$

OR

$$b_2(a_1+a_2)-a_2(b_1+b_2)=?$$