# Show that GCD is = relative prime

Tags: divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

> Let $k$ be an integer. Show that $3k + 2$ and $5k + 3$ are relatively prime.

So, I know that I need to prove that GCD is $1$ and I know that one way to do this is $am+bn=1$. However, I don't really see how to do that here.

Comment: you should edit the title, it makes no sense in the present form

Comment: $\gcd (3 k+2,5 k+3) =\gcd (3 k+2,2 k+1) =\\=\gcd (2 k+1,k+1) =\gcd (k+1,k) =\gcd (k,1)=1$

Answer (score 2):

Eliminate $k$

$$3(5k+3)-5(3k+2)=?$$

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2462741/show-that-if-a-1b-2-−-a-2b-1-pm-1-then-the-gcd-of-a-1-a-2-b-1-b-2/2462745#2462745

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Eucledean algorithm.

$$
5k+3=1\cdot(3k+2)+2k+1
$$
$$
3k+1=1\cdot(2k+1)+k
$$
$$
2k+1=2\cdot k+1
$$
$$
k=k\cdot 1+0
$$
and the last non-zero remainder is the greatest common divisor, which is $1$ and hence they are relative primes.

Comment: In other words, they are coprime in $\mathbb Z[k]$ by direct computation, and therefore remain coprime when you substitute a concrete value for $k$.